# Is inbound traffic allowed on open sockets?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, firewall, communication

ISPs tend to block all inbound traffic. What if I keep the socket alive after the initial handshake with a remote server, and the protocol doesn't impose any limit on how long the socket can be kept open. Can the server send traffic towards me without needing the client to first send a request? I read somewhere that's how push servers work. But I'm confused how this is possible. Isn't the socket just a resource allocated by the two endpoints (client and server)? How is my ISP supposed to know anything about the opened connections to not drop inbound traffic in the middle?

Comment: If ISPs blocked all inbound traffic your internet connection would be completely useless. Off topic.

Comment: "*ISPs tend to block all inbound traffic*" - if an ISP blocked all inbound *traffic* then most Internet protocols would break since servers would not be able to send responses back to clients that are running on ISP customer machines. What ISPs generally block is inbound *connections*, so that customers don't run their own servers, unless they pay extra for that feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ISPs tend to block all inbound traffic.

This is not generally true. It is usually the case though, that NAT (Network Address Translation) is involved to map multiple internal IP addresses to a single public visible IP address. Due to how NAT works it will implicitly block inbound traffic, since it cannot find a matching NAT state.

NAT is done almost always at the home router and it might additionally be done at the ISP (CGNAT - Carrier Grade NAT).

> How is my ISP supposed to know anything about the opened connections to not drop inbound traffic in the middle?

The ISP (in case of CGNAT) and your home router have a state table which match internal connections (before NAT) to the rewritten ones (after NAT). If data arrive from the internet it will try to map these against the state table and rewrite the packets back. If no state exists the packet is discarded.

> What if I keep the socket alive after the initial handshake with a remote server, and the protocol doesn't impose any limit on how long the socket can be kept open. Can the server send traffic towards me without needing the client to first send a request?

Even if the port is actually blocked for connections initiated from the outside it is usually possible to initiate arbitrary connections from the inside. Ones these are established it is possible to send any data back. This is achieved by a technique similar to NAT but without the actual address translation - a stateful firewall.

The request and response pattern you mention is actually more specific to protocols like HTTP, but other protocols like SSH, WebSockets etc don't use this approach anyway.

Both with NAT and with stateful firewalls you have to make sure that the stat is not deleted. States are deleted after some (device specific) timeout of inactivity and once this is done no inbound data will be forwarded. The state is kept open by either sending actual application data or using TCP keep alive (which is a heartbeat without application data).

Comment: What about devices running on sim cards? They don't rely on home routers.

Comment: @Devashish: *"running on sim cards"* - I assume that you mean devices using the mobile network. It is pretty common that CGNAT is implemented there.

Comment: Note that if you have IPv6 then you probably don't have NAT.